# nsuserdefault crashing when fetching objectforkey

Tags: iphone, nsuserdefaults

I have a few images stored in the NSUserDefault dictionary which I am using in various places in my app.

my code

```
  userDefault=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
  if([userDefault objectForKey:flgString]) {
```

Crash scenario is **rare**, and only the first time my app loads (when all cache data is empty).
Once all images are fetched from the server and loaded in the cache, it never crashes.

Below is the crash log, any ideas?

```
#0  0x01afca67 in objc_msgSend ()
#1  0x019cffdf in kCFCoreFoundationVersionNumber ()
#2  0x019b33d8 in __CFBasicHashStandardEquateKeys ()
#3  0x019b1fe7 in ___CFBasicHashFindBucket_Linear ()
#4  0x018bd632 in CFBasicHashFindBucket ()
#5  0x018bd50c in CFDictionaryGetValue ()
#6  0x018e273b in -[CFXPreferencesPropertyListSource getValueForKey:] ()
#7  0x018e26c6 in -[CFXPreferencesSearchListSource getValueForKey:] ()
#8  0x018df0ee in CFPreferencesCopyAppValue ()
#9  0x002d42e8 in -[NSUserDefaults(NSUserDefaults) objectForKey:] ()
#10 0x000f8633 in -[XController tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:]
```

**EDIT**
I am not storing UIImage in the userdefault but instead storing NSData.

Comment: U need to uncode decode while saving and retreving data? not sure about that

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are putting objects in your user defaults that are not of the basic [property-list](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFPropertyLists/Articles/StructureAndContents.html) types. That's not allowed.

Comment: I am not storing UIImage in the userdefault but instead storing NSData, i think that is allowed.

Answer (score 0):

The "key" must be not nil ,the crash is "flgString" is nil ,if it is nil,you can set @"" for it .

the right code

```
userDefault=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

if([userDefault objectForKey:(flgString?:@"")]) {
```